# issues in Y-axis when rotating a JS object in HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, rotation, html5-canvas

I'm trying to make the ball move on the line while rotating **with easing**.. My problem is that while rotating the line the Y-Axis of the ball is changed.

**Note**

Maybe in my code  when rotating the line the whole canvas is rotated but I don't know how to fix it.

**Demo**
http://jsfiddle.net/mgazzar/o487tnb5/38/

here is how the line drawn

```
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2);
ctx.rotate(angle * Math.PI / 180) ;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(-lineLength/2,0);
ctx.lineTo(lineLength/2,0);
ctx.lineWidth=5;
ctx.strokeStyle='white';
ctx.fillStlye = "white";
    ctx.stroke();
ctx.restore();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line code is fine, the problem is with how you are rendering the ball. In the line drawing you properly run `ctx.translate(canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2)` before the `ctx.rotate` so that the line rotates around the center of the canvas. However you do not do anything similar in `ball2.draw`, so the ball is rotating around 0,0 on the canvas, the upper left corner of the canvas.

You can fix this by doing the appropriate `ctx.translate` before rotating the canvas (1 below). But then you need to be careful to also do the reverse translation (2) after the rotation. If not, your ball will be drawn with this.x,this.y relative to the center of the canvas, rather than relative to the upper left corner of the (rotated) screen, as desired.

```
    // Function for drawing ball on canvas
draw: function() {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.translate(canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2);      // 1
    ctx.rotate(angle * Math.PI / 180) ;
    ctx.translate(-canvas.width/2,-canvas.height/2);    // 2
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **Robert Penners famous easing equations** to rotate your object with an easing effect:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;


var easingType='easeOutBounce';
var PI=Math.PI;
var x=60;
var y=100;
var circumference;
var minAngle=0;
var maxAngle=PI*4;
var currentT=0;
var maxT=100;

var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/ball1.png";
function start(){
  circumference=PI*img.width;
  drawBall(x,y,0);
  animate();
}


function animate(){
  if(currentT<maxT){requestAnimationFrame(animate);}

  var easedAngle=Easings[easingType](currentT,minAngle,maxAngle,maxT);
  var easedX=x+easedAngle/maxAngle*circumference*2;
  drawBall(easedX,y,easedAngle);

  currentT+=1;
}

function drawBall(x,y,rAngle){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  ctx.fillRect(0,y,cw,1);
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(x,y);
  ctx.rotate(rAngle);
  ctx.drawImage(img,-img.width/2,-img.height/2);
  ctx.restore();
}

// Robert Penner's easing algorithms
// t: current time, 
// b: begInnIng value, 
// c: change In value, 
// d: duration
Easings={

  easeLinear: function(t, b, c, d){

  },

  swing: function (t, b, c, d) {
    return jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def](t, b, c, d);
  },
  easeInQuad: function (t, b, c, d) {
    return c*(t/=d)*t + b;
  },
  easeOutQuad: function (t, b, c, d) {
    return -c *(t/=d)*(t-2) + b;
  },
  easeInOutQuad: function (t, b, c, d) {
    if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t + b;
    return -c/2 * ((--t)*(t-2) - 1) + b;
  },
  easeInCubic: function (t, b, c, d) {
    return c*(t/=d)*t*t + b;
  },
  easeOutCubic: function (t, b, c, d) {
    return c*((t=t/d-1)*t*t + 1) + b;
  },
  easeInOutCubic: function (t, b, c, d) {
    if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t*t + b;
    return c/2*((t-=2)*t*t + 2) + b;
  },
  easeInQuart: function (t, b, c, d) {
    return c*(t/=d)*t*t*t + b;
  },
  easeOutQuart: function (t, b, c, d) {
    return -c * ((t=t/d-1)*t*t*t - 1) + b;
  },
  easeInOutQuart: function (t, b, c, d) {
    if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t*t*t + b;
    return -c/2 * ((t-=2)*t*t*t - 2) + b;
  },
  easeInQuint: function (t, b, c, d) {
    return c*(t/=d)*t*t*t*t + b;
  },
  easeOutQuint: function (t, b, c, d) {
    return c*((t=t/d-1)*t*t*t*t + 1) + b;
  },
  easeInOutQuint: function (t, b, c, d) {
    if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t*t*t*t + b;
    return c/2*((t-=2)*t*t*t*t + 2) + b;
  },
  easeInSine: function (t, b, c, d) {
    return -c * Math.cos(t/d * (Math.PI/2)) + c + b;
  },
  easeOutSine: function (t, b, c, d) {
    return c * Math.sin(t/d * (Math.PI/2)) + b;
  },
  easeInOutSine: function (t, b, c, d) {
    return -c/2 * (Math.cos(Math.PI*t/d) - 1) + b;
  },
  easeInExpo: function (t, b, c, d) {
    return (t==0) ? b : c * Math.pow(2, 10 * (t/d - 1)) + b;
  },
  easeOutExpo: function (t, b, c, d) {
    return (t==d) ? b+c : c * (-Math.pow(2, -10 * t/d) + 1) + b;
  },
  easeInOutExpo: function (t, b, c, d) {
    if (t==0) return b;
    if (t==d) return b+c;
    if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2 * Math.pow(2, 10 * (t - 1)) + b;
    return c/2 * (-Math.pow(2, -10 * --t) + 2) + b;
  },
  easeInCirc: function (t, b, c, d) {
    return -c * (Math.sqrt(1 - (t/=d)*t) - 1) + b;
  },
  easeOutCirc: function (t, b, c, d) {
    return c * Math.sqrt(1 - (t=t/d-1)*t) + b;
  },
  easeInOutCirc: function (t, b, c, d) {
    if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return -c/2 * (Math.sqrt(1 - t*t) - 1) + b;
    return c/2 * (Math.sqrt(1 - (t-=2)*t) + 1) + b;
  },
  easeInElastic: function (t, b, c, d) {
    var s=1.70158;var p=0;var a=c;
    if (t==0) return b;  if ((t/=d)==1) return b+c;  if (!p) p=d*.3;
    if (a < Math.abs(c)) { a=c; var s=p/4; }
    else var s = p/(2*Math.PI) * Math.asin (c/a);
    return -(a*Math.pow(2,10*(t-=1)) * Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*Math.PI)/p )) + b;
  },
  easeOutElastic: function (t, b, c, d) {
    var s=1.70158;var p=0;var a=c;
    if (t==0) return b;  if ((t/=d)==1) return b+c;  if (!p) p=d*.3;
    if (a < Math.abs(c)) { a=c; var s=p/4; }
    else var s = p/(2*Math.PI) * Math.asin (c/a);
    return a*Math.pow(2,-10*t) * Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*Math.PI)/p ) + c + b;
  },
  easeInOutElastic: function (t, b, c, d) {
    var s=1.70158;var p=0;var a=c;
    if (t==0) return b;  if ((t/=d/2)==2) return b+c;  if (!p) p=d*(.3*1.5);
    if (a < Math.abs(c)) { a=c; var s=p/4; }
    else var s = p/(2*Math.PI) * Math.asin (c/a);
    if (t < 1) return -.5*(a*Math.pow(2,10*(t-=1)) * Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*Math.PI)/p )) + b;
    return a*Math.pow(2,-10*(t-=1)) * Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*Math.PI)/p )*.5 + c + b;
  },
  easeInBack: function (t, b, c, d, s) {
    if (s == undefined) s = 1.70158;
    return c*(t/=d)*t*((s+1)*t - s) + b;
  },
  easeOutBack: function (t, b, c, d, s) {
    if (s == undefined) s = 1.70158;
    return c*((t=t/d-1)*t*((s+1)*t + s) + 1) + b;
  },
  easeInOutBack: function (t, b, c, d, s) {
    if (s == undefined) s = 1.70158; 
    if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*(t*t*(((s*=(1.525))+1)*t - s)) + b;
    return c/2*((t-=2)*t*(((s*=(1.525))+1)*t + s) + 2) + b;
  },
  easeInBounce: function (t, b, c, d) {
    return c - jQuery.easing.easeOutBounce (d-t, 0, c, d) + b;
  },
  easeOutBounce: function (t, b, c, d) {
    if ((t/=d) < (1/2.75)) {
      return c*(7.5625*t*t) + b;
    } else if (t < (2/2.75)) {
      return c*(7.5625*(t-=(1.5/2.75))*t + .75) + b;
    } else if (t < (2.5/2.75)) {
      return c*(7.5625*(t-=(2.25/2.75))*t + .9375) + b;
    } else {
      return c*(7.5625*(t-=(2.625/2.75))*t + .984375) + b;
    }
  },
  easeInOutBounce: function (t, b, c, d) {
    if (t < d/2) return jQuery.easing.easeInBounce (t*2, 0, c, d) * .5 + b;
    return jQuery.easing.easeOutBounce (t*2-d, 0, c, d) * .5 + c*.5 + b;
  }
};
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<p>Moving and Rotating with 'InQuad' easing</p>
<canvas id="canvas" width=550 height=200></canvas><br>
```

Comment: Thank you , but if there any simple easing tool with pure JS ?

Comment: The relevant code is all pure javascript--I just used jQuery by habit to handle the again-button-click.  I've pulled the jQuery out of my demo and now it's pure javascript. Good luck with your project!